# STM32F334 Nucleo-64 ADC speed

Tags: adc, speed

I have a problem with my ADC speed. I'd like to have a speed over 1 MSPS but I get only 60 KSPS. I use a very basic code that uses ADC interrupt to stock the value into a table and when the full data measurement is done I upload the samples using UART to see the results.

To evaluate the speed I apply a 10 kHz square signal on the ADC pin and look at the number of High and Low levels.

Both ADC and core work at 32 MHz.

Someone knows where is the problem ?

[image]

Comment: Does HAL_ADC_Start_IT need to be called for every conversion? I'm not sure. Especially since you have "else stop". Why would you need stop if interrupt ADC stops after every conversion. Also, please add code as "code", not as screenshot

Comment: [Code syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting); you just have to replace `lang-js` with `lang-c`.

Comment: @Ilya stop is used to start UART transfer at the end of the measurement so it's not really important

Comment: only replacing lang-js with lang-c and it should work ?

Comment: You maybe wrote simple code, but HAL code is anything but simple code. I would guess HAL code reinitialize ADC registers every sample. I would also look at possibility of using DMA which could even simplify your code (and probably even solve slow HAL code problem).

Comment: @Rokta Ok I will try this, thank you.